# Are the only Riemann surfaces which are quotients of $\mathbb{C}$the cylinder and the toruses? Why?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, quotient-spaces, integer-lattices

Consider the Riemann surfaces $\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice in the complex plane (i.e. a discrete additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$). Now, we can show that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is biholomorphic to the quotient $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is considered as an additive subgroup, so both of these are quotients.  I've heard somebody say, pretty long ago, that these are the *only* Riemann surfaces that arise as quotients of the complex plane. Is this true? If so, why?

Answer (score 4):

By the uniformisation theorem, a Riemann surface is a quotient of
a simply connected Riemann surface $S$ by a discrete subgroup consisting
of biholomorphic maps on $S$, consisting, apart from the identity, of maps
without fixed points. Note that $S$ is biholomorphic to $\Bbb C$, the Riemann sphere, or the upper half-plane.

The biholomorphic maps from $\Bbb C$ to itself are $z\mapsto az+b$
with $a$, $b\in \Bbb C$, $a\ne0$. The ones without fixed points are those
with $a=1$, the translations. The only discrete subgroups of fixed-point-free
biholomorphic maps are (i) the trivial group, (ii) cyclic generated by a translation, (iii) consisting of translations forming a rank $2$ lattice.

The quotients of $\Bbb C$ by these groups are (i) $\Bbb C$, (ii) $\Bbb C^\times$ and (iii) complex tori.